# Can't Hide Error Messages with Wordpress 5.0

Tags: php, wordpress

Our Wordpress was updated to 5.0 overnight, and we now have an error message showing at the top of all webpages:

Everything still works accordingly, and I really just need to hide the error code, but since the update it seems the warning message can't be hidden. I have the following code already added to my wp-config.php file:

```
 ini_set('log_errors','On');
 ini_set('display_errors','Off');
 ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
 define('WP_DEBUG', false);
 define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
 define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

But I am still seeing the following error code:

> Warning: Declaration of WC_Product_Booking::get_price() should be
>   compatible with WC_Product::get_price($context = 'view') in
>   /public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/includes/class-wc-product-booking.php
>   on line 0

How can I hide this? Did 5.0 remove the ability to hide error codes?

Comment: ** Update: I never did figure this out, but instead focused on resolving the error message, which was a PHP problem.

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

### * Editing the display_errors :

Go to the website's cPanel, search for and click on
*[Select PHP Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD5AZ.png)*, inside *`PHP Selector`*, select *`Options`*, under *`PHP Options`*, untick the **[display_errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXkRd.png)** ☐ radio box.

---

** If **Method 1** didn't work, try **Method 2**.*

---

## Method 2

### * Editing the functions.php :

Add these codes into the **functions.php** file - located in the WordPress' *`Appearance > Theme File Editor`* > [Theme Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huehS.png) :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
error_reporting(0);
```

---

** Please note that it is a better practice to fix the errors instead of hiding them.*

---

Answer (score 0):

Try setting error_reporting to 0 instead of E_ALL and see if it works

```
 ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference.